# File size limit in Metadata creation in Talend for XML file?

Tags: xml, talend

I am trying to create metadata for XML file in Talend. It is around 12 MB. But since its not responding my application.  My RAM is 12 G.

I tried with small  size file then it is working fine. I do not know why its not working for large files.

Comment: What have you experienced? What does "not responding" mean exactly? Do you know about the RAM usage of Eclipse? Did you change heap sizes? How long did you wait?

Comment: I am using Ta-lend open studio for Big data not "eclipse".  not responding means application hang out once upload file. i waited around 20 min.

Comment: Talend (written without a hyphen) Studio is based on Eclipse. You might want to change the heap size. An example you see here http://kindleconsulting.com/component/zoo/item/managing-jvm-heap-size-in-talend-open-studio.html You need to change the .ini file corresponding to your OS.

Answer (score 0):

check available mem during process, if this looks to hit peak but then stop your probably correct, however if this looks just to be in normal parameters then it could be a data issue. Try larger size but with known data replicated out to fill memory test. This would prove its a data issue rather than memory.